# Theorem about real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let X be any finite set of positive real numbers whose arithmetic average is 1. 
How can you prove that the arithmetic average of X*ln(X) > 0?

It seems almost self evident from the graph of x ln(x), and it's pretty easy to show that the integral over any interval symmetric about 1 is positive. That's almost a proof, but not quite (since it applies only to infinite random sets with uniform distribution, where the sums converge to the integral)

Seems like it should be simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What if $X=\{1\}$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=x\ln x$ is convex, so it follows (with $\ge0$ for the case mentioned by @lulu) from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: Jensen's inequality was just what I needed.